# GCloud java error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, java-8, gcloud

I am trying to create an api of stores which the following attributes:
StoreId, Name, Location, Phone, List of products (ProductId,Object,Price,Stock), Size of List Products

The problem is that when the store is iniciated with items in List, it response with this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed
> at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$ResponseWrapper.checkNotCommitted(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:628)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$ResponseWrapper.sendError(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:714)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleFailure(SynchronousDispatcher.java:283)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleWriterException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:417)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:237)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleWriteResponseException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:221)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:531)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:599)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

However, if all stores has no items, there is no problem, but if all stores haven't items, the api is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused because someone else in the team wrote the class Product, trying to reference the store with its name but putting all the store as an argument, referencing the object store inside the same object store.